# C# Json.Net - How to deserialize complex object Google Elevation

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "elevation" : 25.51896667480469,
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -26.90408425509977,
            "lng" : -49.04650926589966
         },
         "resolution" : 152.7032318115234
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

This class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Elevacao[] results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}


public class Elevacao
{
    public Decimal elevation { get; set; }
    public Decimal resolution { get; set; }
    public dados[] location { get; set; }                
}

public class dados
{
    public Decimal lat { get; set; }
    public Decimal lng { get; set; } 
}
```

This code:

```
public ActionResult Teste()
{
    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations=-26.904084255099768,-49.04650926589966&sensor=false&format=json";
    var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

    RootObject m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

    return View();
}
```

And this error:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'TCC.Controllers.dados[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'results[0].location.lat', line 6, position 20.
```

where I went wrong?

Comment: You mispasted your error.

Comment: I think instead of the error you printed your action result twice

Comment: What part of the clear and extremely detailed error message don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON, `location` is an object, not an array.  However, in your `Elevacao` class `location` is defined as an array.  They need to match in order for deserialization to work correctly.  That is what the error message is trying to tell you.

To fix it, change this line:

```
public dados[] location { get; set; }
```

To this:

```
public dados location { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

`location` in your JSON is a single object, not an array.

Comment: How do I fix the problem? @SLaks

Comment: @marlon.tiedt: Change the property in your class to not be an array.

Answer (score 1):

You want "results" from the JSONObject. Use `json.results`